# Add fragment at runtime with Kotlin causes 'Unfortunately app has stopped'

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I am trying to run fragment at runtime but my app crashes with message 'Unfortunately app has stopped'

Here is my Fragment kotlin class:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

    class TestFragment : Fragment() {

        override fun onCreateView (inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, container, false)
        }

    }
```

Frame layout beggins with:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/testFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

And here is my activity:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_display_text.*

class DisplayText : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_text)

        var toDisplay = intent.extras.get("MainActivity_HELLO_WORLD")
        displayText.text = toDisplay as String

        if(R.id.testFragment !== null) {

            if(savedInstanceState !== null) {
                return
            }

            val fragment = TestFragment()

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.testFragment, fragment).commit()

        }
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please provide your LogCat output at the time of the crash

Comment: Yes.  I can tell you exactly what you are doing wrong:  You are asking a question, on StackOverflow, without including the actual error message.  Doing this is likely to get you down-voted.

Comment: 09-14 14:51:41.096 6498-6498/com.corcode.myapplication E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f070075 (com.corcode.myapplication:id/testFragment) for fragment TestFragment{dcf770e #0 id=0x7f070075}

Comment: `R.id.testFragment` is an integer identifier. It's never null.

Answer (score 1):

This method call is wrong :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.testFragment, fragment).commit()
```

because the first param of the add method should be your fragment container (the layout in your activity which will receive the frament).

Here you are trying to pass the layout of your fragment, which is not part of the currently inflated view hierachy. So the FragmentManager is looking in the view hierarchy for a view that does not exist, and it crashes.

You need to pass there the id of a valid ViewGroup. We usually use a FrameLayout as a fragment container.
And this container needs to be included in the layout.xml of your activity

Hope this helps.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the answer